# webrtc audio_processing: what is keyboard channel in StreamConfig?

Tags: audio, keyboard, webrtc, audio-processing

At [webrtc/modules/audio_processing/include/audio_processing.h](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/main/modules/audio_processing/include/audio_processing.h#830) class StreamConfig there is an option **has_keyboard**, my question is what it is? and How to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the keyboard microphone channel and by default it will be used if the user's keyboard has a microphone.

If you look at `helpers.cc`:

```
webrtc::StreamConfig CreateStreamConfig(const AudioParameters& parameters) {
  int channels = parameters.channels();
  (...)
  const bool has_keyboard = parameters.channel_layout() ==
                            media::CHANNEL_LAYOUT_STEREO_AND_KEYBOARD_MIC;
```